# Access parent attribute from chid class in Python

Tags: class, oop, inheritance, attributes

How can I access attribute `array` in `Parent` class from `Child` class? Here is an example of my code that doesn't work

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __createArray(self): # Private function
        x = self.x
        y = self.y
        array = []
        array.append(f(x), f(y)) # f() is a random function 
        
        self.array = array 
        return array

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__(x, y)

    def __create2ndArray(self): # Private function
        x = self.x
        y = self.y

        # This line below doesn't work
        array = self.array
```

Many people tell me to use `super()` function but I still don't know how. But it looks like I can't use `super()` in this situation since it only use for methods, not attributes

Answer (score 1):

```
class Parent:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def _createArray(self):  # Protected function - children cannot run private
        x = self.x
        y = self.y
        array = []
        f = lambda x: x
        array.append(f(x))  # f() is a random function
        array.append(f(y))
        self.array = array
        return array


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__(x, y)

    def create2ndArray(self):  # Public function - so that I can run it
        super()._createArray()
        x = self.x
        y = self.y

        # This line below doesn't work
        array = self.array
        print(array)

x = Child(3,4)
x.create2ndArray()
```

You have never ran `__createArray()` method in child so `self.array` was `None`